# Creating inequalities and Bounds

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

I am self-studying real analysis and I am facing a challenge when it comes to create bounds. For example, the 3.12(b) exercise from baby Rudin:

[image]

I understood the proof completely. My only problem is that multiplying by $(\sqrt{r_n}+\sqrt{r_{n+1}})$ came from nowhere. I do not know how could I do this by myself.

And this is not special for this example only, I can see it as a general theme when it comes to crafting and engendering these bounds.

Where can I study about these techniques? or is it more of an art than a knowledge?

Any insight?

Comment: Here they asked you to prove something involving $\sqrt{r_n}-\sqrt{r_{n+1}}$ which is very recognisably able to be rationalised by a difference of two squares technique: $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$ is a very famous and very common identity, so it would have been reasonable to try to involve $\sqrt{r_n}+\sqrt{r_{n+1}}$. Problem solving is hit and miss, but this in particular is a common thing likely to hit!

Comment: Thanks @IdioticShrike, I agree with you. and I can see why they have asked to prove this property before they have asked about proving the convergence. But in the other hand, if I were asked to proof this series without any context, I cannot see how could I come up with this trick. And usually when things involve creating bounds, things get way too elegant for my taste. So, is there a topic or a place where I can cover some of these techniques or methods?

Comment: First of all, I am just a school student of math myself. Secondly, in my limited but highly curious studies and experience of maths, I find that my ability to see statements and understand them for myself, without seeing the formal proof first, grows only with time and pattern recognition. As if often the case with any discipline, you can only immerse yourself in it to gain a fluency and intuition for it; seek the challenging problems and hope for the best. Every statement and proof looks like absolute genius, so just read lots of them to let the genius rub off...

Comment: Also, one thing to be aware of solutions, is that just because it's presented that way, doesn't mean that was the exact path (from start to finish) that someone took to get there. One possible start is to compare the numerators, and if one realizes that $ a_n = ( \sqrt{ r_n } - \sqrt{ r_{n+1}} ) ( \sqrt{ r_n } + \sqrt{ r_{n+1}} )$, then that substitution would likely move us towards the goal. This in turn means we want to show that $( \sqrt{ r_n } + \sqrt{ r_{n+1} }) < 2 \sqrt{ r_n } $, which is obvious. We can then see how they chose to present it all in one line.